# python 2.7: Debugging an if-else statement (syntax error)

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement

I'm new to coding in python and trying to incorporate an if-else statement into existing code. However, when I run the segment I get an error that reads:

```
else:
   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Here is the new code I am running. Where did I go wrong?

```
if value[4] > 0: ref = value[0] / value[4]
else:
    ref = "NA"
if value[5] > 0: alt = value[1] / value[5]
else:
    alt = "NA"
diff = ref_meth-alt_meth
p = pvalue(*value[0:4]).two_tail
output += "%s,%s,%s,%s\n" % (ref, alt, diff, p)
#Note that the two if-else statements are separate from one another so I don't want to use elif.
```

This is the original code that works except when value[4] or value[5] equals 0.

```
ref = value[0] / value[4]
alt = value[1] / value[5]
diff = ref_meth-alt_meth
p = pvalue(*value[0:4]).two_tail
output += "%s,%s,%s,%s\n" % (ref, alt, diff, p)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that's common in Python is strange syntax errors due to strange white spaces. This is likely in a case like this, but it is impossible to say for certain, because white spaces simply do not translate very well during copy paste. I copy pasted your code, and it worked, proving there's no syntax errors. And since it solved your problem I also put it here as a reminder for others.

Often this problem gets solved by simply removing the newline and then put it back again.

Answer (score 0):

Python is a language that detects the indentation to if the piece of code falls, for example, under if or else statement. The code given above is only a block or piece of code that you are trying to enter and because I don't know the whole program I am finding it tough to debug that. Try writing the code in a following manner:

```
if value[4] > 0: 
    ref = value[0] / value[4]
else:
    ref = "NA"
if value[5] > 0: 
    alt = value[1] / value[5]
else:
    alt = "NA"
diff = ref_meth-alt_meth
p = pvalue(*value[0:4]).two_tail
output += "%s,%s,%s,%s\n" % (ref, alt, diff, p)
```

Make sure to have the indentation levels of the blocks inside if and else same. Just to inform you as python does not use any brackets it detects when a particular code is inside a block by use of indentation. So for python your code needs to be in proper indentation to run.

You can also refer to the official documentation of Python 2.7 for [if and else](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html).

Hope this helps!!!